# Magento 1.8 - Admin forgot email transactionsemail template?

Tags: magento, email, admin

I have problems with the password forgot function,
at customers i have added these code:

```
<a href="{{store url="customer/account/resetpassword/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.rp_token}}"><br><br>{{store url="customer/account/resetpassword/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.rp_token}}</a>
```

but what is the code for admin reset link.
these one is not the right reset link. its invalid.

Comment: the default template sends no email link and  an emtpy password
Thanks for your help i will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin link is generated with this directive:

`{{store url="adminhtml/index/resetpassword/" _query_id=$user.id  query_token=$user.rp_token}}`.

You can find the link yourself when loading the default template in backend in the transactional email menu.